# The difference of "for" and "at" in the following sentences

Tags: prepositions

What are the differences between "at" and "for" in the following sentences:

> We scheduled the party ***at*** 7:00.
>
> We scheduled the party ***for*** 7:00.

Answer (score 4):

> We scheduled the party for 7:00.

means *We decided the party would start at 7:00.*

> We scheduled the party at 7:00.

could mean one of two things: *At 7:00, we decided what time the party would start.* **or** *We decided the party would start at 7:00.*

If you want to say that the party will start at 7:00, using *for* is somewhat more natural than *at* (potentially because *at* could have an alternate meaning as well).

Comment: I'll be happy to upvote if you are more specific about it.

Comment: The version with *at* can also have the other meaning.

Comment: I think the latter could be read *the party [to be] at 7:00* or *the party[; it's] at 7:00*. Using *for* would be more natural and correct, but in proper context (especially informal spoken English), people would understand *at* as meaning the same thing.

Comment: @TimS. You''re right, I wasn't sure if it was just me :)